# Multiple Capybara wait times?

Tags: capybara

I want to have different `Capybara` wait times in my code depending on how much time they usually take to load completely? Do I have to repetitively keep changing the `Capybara.default_wait_time` or is there a better way?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can use [using_wait_time(seconds)](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara.using_wait_time) method like:

```
using_wait_time 3 do
  expect(page).to have_text 'Lorem ipsum'
end
```

or `:wait` option (that appeared in Capybara 2.1).

Note that `:wait` option was supported only by `find` method in Capybara 2.1.

Support for `:wait` option in matchers (i.e. `has_x?` and `have_x` methods) has been added in Capybara 2.2:

```
expect(page).to have_text('Lorem ipsum', wait: 3)
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks for mentioning the upcoming support.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, but is this not just a fancy way of using sleep(x) ?

Comment: @Dono `sleep` will always pause for `x`. `have_text` will pause for time up to `x` (until text will appear).

Comment: @AndreyBotalov I understand that, What I mean is the use of wait: x  Is that not just a fancy sleep?

Comment: @Dono https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/2.4.1/lib/capybara/node/base.rb#L90

Comment: @Dono its fanciness grants specific advantages; per the docs and Andrey.  "up to" is a critical term, here.

Comment: Ah okay. Sounds sensible. Either way it is better than explicitly putting a sleep in :)

Comment: A few questions for any experts available: If I set `Capybara.default_wait_time`, then does this override that? Does it matter where I set `Capybara.default_wait_time`? Is there a way I can check within a test what wait time it is using? Is there a way I can check to see how much time it waited when there is a failure? Is all this the same for all drivers? Thanks!