# How to verify when a regexp value in a js pop up becomes visible in capybara/cucumber

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, cucumber, capybara

I am automating a feature where a pop up dialog starts an audit showing a page value of 0 as a status, but then this value changes to a non-zero value. I need to verify the non-zero value when it appears so that I can click on an ok button and continue the process. There is no `wait_until` in capybara. So the capybara test needs to "wait" until my regex becomes true. I tried several options, and this is my last one, which is failing. Using "sleep" is not the right way to go.

```
find(:xpath, '//*[@id="pageKeywords"]', :text => /"[1-9][1-9]" pages processed/).should be_visible
```

But this is not doing the trick as the test finds the audit while it is on "0 pages processed" and fails. How can I go about this?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346314/multiple-capybara-wait-times

Comment: xpath has a `fn:matches` see http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp to allow regrex comparison. Maybe you can use this.

Answer (score 0):

Capybara tries to do this on its own, but I'm guessing that the audit takes longer than Capybara is prepared to wait. Let's say your spec sets an expectation along the lines of:

```
expect(page).to have_css('#pageKeywords', text: %r{"[1-9][1-9]" pages processed}, visible: true)
```

Capybara *will wait* for awhile for this to happen. The [`synchronize`](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/base.rb#L44) method handles this, by catching `Capybara::ElementNotFound` exceptions for a number of seconds specified in `Capybara.default_wait_time`. However, you can allow Capybara to wait even longer by passing your expectation as a block to `Capybara.with_wait_time`:

```
Capybara.with_wait_time(30) do
  expect(page).to have_css('#pageKeywords', text: %r{"[1-9][1-9]" pages processed}, visible: true)
end
```

Boom! Now Capybara will wait 30 seconds before giving up on satisfying the expectation.